# Deploy doesn't support the nested "bundleArgument" element

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am trying with `sbt-native-packager` plugin for my project, but getting error `fx:deploy doesn't support the nested "bundleArgument" element` while running `jdkPackager:packageBin` command. Can anyone help in sorting out the issue. Thanks in advance.

My build.sbt

> name := "packaging"
>
> version := "1.0"
>
> scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
>
> name := "JDKPackagerPlugin Example"
>
> version := "0.1.0"
>
> organization := "com.test"
>
> libraryDependencies ++= Seq(   "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1" )
>
> mainClass in Compile := Some("com.test.packaging.MainClass")
>
> enablePlugins(JDKPackagerPlugin)

My Main Class

```
 object MainClass extends App {

   println("Hello, World!!!") 
 }
```

My plugins.sbt

> addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.3")

Answer (score 2):

As of 1.0.3, this isn't yet supported directly via an sbt key. You can work around it by intercepting/redefining the [`antBuildDefn` task](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/jdkpackager/JDKPackagerKeys.scala#L94) to insert additional elements into the build definition DOM before it's written out and passed to Ant.

That said, supporting the `bundleArgument` element is a desirable end goal. I suggest submitting a [feature request](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/new) (or better, submit a working PR!).

Comment: Is this still the same for 1.2.0-M6? It seems to be. Happy to attempt a PR but might need a few more pointers. Can you point me at some examples of well formed (Ant) XML that we'd need? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_task_reference.html#CACDDFDF didn't help much.